# Need documentation for Microsoft.Azure.Kusto.Data

Tags: c#, .net, azure-data-explorer

I have been unable to find proper documentation for Microsoft.Azure.Kusto.Data nuget package apart from https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-dotnet which doesn't really contain any code or documentation around the methods used. Where else can I look for more information ?

Comment: Nothing new in this regards, quite a bunch of projects don't have any. What you could do is search about specific namespaces, sometimes you end up on projects that can help you understand how to use these.

Answer (score 2):

See here for docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/netfx/about-the-sdk

And here for code examples: https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-samples-dotnet

Comment: Actually I am more interested in methods inside CslCommandGenerator which can't be found in these docs.

Comment: Anything specific, or broad documentation?